# Say My Name Please

Tags: riddle, knowledge, lateral-thinking, language

> People, demons, deities--
>   These three love to follow me.
>
> Starving, penniless--where reside thee?
>   I may satiate or be half your need.
>
> Cupboards, crumbs, committees--
>   Those are different yet still come with me.
>
> Always carousing, happy and merry;
>   Yet wake me up and you may see:
>
> Disaster, alarm, anxiety--
>   All those come out when I shriek.

---

**Hints 1-4**

> 1. It also makes sense if you replace 'people' by 'diseases.' (This hint used to say it also makes sense if you replace 'diseases' by 'people' but the new ordering is more consistent with what I want to convey)
> 2. These are all associated with the [language](/questions/tagged/language) tag:
>
> *these three love to follow me*
>
> *those are different yet still come with me*
>
> *where reside thee*
> 3. I am three letters long.
> 4. "These three love to follow me" -> If you put these 3 behind me, you get 3 words.

**Update:** User477343 is correct that the intended answer is

> PAN

However, there are still lots of clues left to be solved! Below you can find a diagram (a very badly made one) that shows which clues are unsolved/solved. (I've pulled the clues from the answers, so everyone can see what is left to solve)

> Line 1/2 -> pandemic (somebody),  pandemonium (mdlha), pantheon (mdlha)
>  Line 3/4 -> ______,  pan (kitchen tool) (user477343)
>  Line 5/6 -> pantry (mdlha), panko (mdlha), panel (mdlha)
>  What makes the clues from lines 5/6 different from those from 1/2? ______
>  Line 7 -> Pan (Greek god) (JonMark Perry)
>  Line 8/9/10 -> ______

Comment: The title is not a clue. I just phrased it that way so it partially rhymes with everything else.

Comment: So hexomino's answer is incorrect?

Comment: Yes; I'm looking for an answer that places a higher emphasis on the language tag for some of the hints.

Comment: I noticed that (ROT13) Lbh hfr fbzr nyyvgrengvba. Sbe rknzcyr, "qvfrnfrf, qrzbaf, qrvgvrf" naq "phcobneqf, pehzcf, pbzzvggrrf" ohg sbe gur ynfg bar, vg qbrfa'g unir gur gev-nyyvgrengvba: "Qvfnfgre, nynez, nakvrgl". Qbrf guvf zrna jr jbhyq unir gb ercynpr "qvfnfgre" jvgu nabgure jbeq yvxr jr qvq sbe "crbcyr"? V nz thrffvat jr ercynpr "qvfnfgre" jvgu "nppvqrag" be fbzrguvat ;)

Comment: The alliteration isn't actually that important. In fact I changed the first line to "People, demons, deities" since I felt that was more correct. (see hint 1)

Comment: Ah I see. Welp, hint 4 has stuffed me up with the answer I have been thinking... eh well, hahah, nice riddle ;)

Comment: Is anyone still working on the clues? I was thinking of posting my intended solutions, since it's been a while.

Comment: Nope, I am still working on it now :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there hasn't been any progress in a while, I thought I should post the intended answer. Portions of the clues were solved already, and credit is distributed accordingly.

The answer is

> PAN (user477343)

People, demons, deities--
these three love to follow me.

> PANDEMIC (somebody), PANDEMONIUM (mdlha), PANTHEON (mdlha)
>  demic -> people, demonium -> demons, deities -> theon

Starving, penniless--where reside thee?
I may satiate or be half your need.

> PAN (bread in Spanish), PAN (cooking tool) (user477343)
>  If you are in a Spanish speaking country, bread is all you need. If you are in an English speaking country, you still need something to cook.

Cupboards, crumbs, committees--
those are different yet still come with me.

> PANTRY (mdlha), PANKO (mdlha), PANEL (mdlha)
>  for those words, PAN is not a root but just happens to be start the word.

Always carousing, happy and merry;

> PAN (Greek deity) (JonMark Perry)

Yet wake me up and you may see:

Disaster, alarm, anxiety--
all those come out when I shriek.

> PANIC
>  If you wake PAN (Greek deity) up, he may utter a terrifying scream. The word PANIC comes from this story and is associated with disaster, alarm, and anxiety.

Answer (score 6):

I think the answer is actually

> Water (agreeing with bw1984)

Disease,

> [Waterborne diseases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waterborne_diseases) are very common.

demons,

> There are several examples of water demons in different mythologies such as the [Rusalka](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rusalka)

deities--

> Wikipedia has an extensive list of [water deities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_water_deities)

These three love to follow me.

> These things are very often associated with the existence of water

Starving, penniless--where reside thee?

> If you reside near a river or lake then water is essentially free.

I may satiate or be half your need.

> Water will quench your thirst but not satisfy your hunger.

Cupboards,

> Water closets

crumbs,

> [Bread and water](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/bread+and+water)

committees--

> Committees are often set up to regulate water supply

Those are different yet still come with me.

> They are not directly linked to water but have derived associations through human interaction.

Always carousing, happy and merry;

> I think this is metaphorical - the gentle flow of a river or the movement of the sea

yet wake me up and you may see:

> Human activity can cause serious flooding (through poorly-planned building or global warming, for example)

Disaster, alarm, anxiety--

> These relate specifically to water-related disasters, either on a local or national scale.

all those come out when I shriek.

> Again metaphorical, could be a river that breaks its banks or a tsunami coming into shore.

Answer (score 6):

Is the answer

> **PAN**?

`People, demons, deities——` 
`These three love to follow me.`

> [**Pan**'s People](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pan%27s_People); [**Pan** (demon and god/deity figure)](https://gnosticwarrior.com/pan.html).

`Starving, penniless——where reside thee?` 
`I may satiate or be half your need`

> You can use **pans** to cook food (if you are starving), and there is also a thing called [gold **pan**ning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gold_panning) to find gold (if you are penniless). 
>  
>  Since you used the archaic word "thee" then I will use the archaic definition of "satiate" which is to be satisfied to the full. Talking about starving, when people are *full*, it usually means they have eaten and are not hungry anymore; they are satisfied. <s>Of course, if you want food, you can look in the **pan**try, for which half that word is "**pan**". 
>  
>  <sub>**Edit:** Thanks to @[stuartstevenson](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/45629/stuart-stevenson), the French annunciation of "pain" is "pan", and "pain" means "bread". This part is important particularly for the following sandbox, but also it ties in to Jesus Christ's command that "man shall not live by bread alone, ..." when Jesus was fastening and poor (starving and penniless) during his temptation from Satan ([here](https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/243100.html)).</sub></s> 
>  
>  **Edit:** You can use regular pans to fry eggs and satisfy your hunger, referring to "starving", and to ***pan**handle* means to beg on the street, which would refer to being "penniless". *Panhandle* is a compound word made up of *pan* and *handle*, so I guess *pan* is half of the entire word in the context of it being compound.

`Cupboards, crumbs, committees——` 
`Those are different yet still come with me.`

> <s>Cupboards and crumbs are once again involved with the **pan**try or just normal **pans**. There is a thing called [**pan**-regions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pan-region) which might involve committees. Pantries, pans, and pan-regions are all different.</s> 
>  
>  **Edit:** Perhaps it could be referring to [**pan** racks](https://www.pinterest.com.au/pin/573857177489258596/) for "cupboards", regular pans for "crumbs", and the [**Pan**-African Parliament](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permanent_Committees_of_the_Pan-African_Parliament) for "committees".

`Always carousing, happy and merry;` 
`Yet wake me up and you may see:`

> Always carousing can cause a **pan**demonium, and someone who is happy and merry (especially because he never grows up) is a familiar guy called Peter **Pan**.

`Disaster, alarm, anxiety——` 
`All those come out when I shriek.`

> Well, a pandemonium can cause a disaster, anxiety and be quite alarming. Also, when Peter Pan **wakes up** Wendy, and her brothers John and Michael, the parents are grief-stricken over their disappearance. The kids of course disappear when they fly out their home and **shriek** in the air towards Neverland. 
>  
>  <sub>**Edit:** thanks to @[KateGregory](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/1509/kate-gregory): "pan pan" is what people on boats would say in the case of an emergency, a step down from saying "mayday" ([here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pan-pan)).</sub>

---

**Title:**

`Say My Name Please`

> <s>An anagram of **say my name please** is **Me? Pan? Yes! Lame, say**. Does this mean anything?</s> *Title is not a clue.*

`Hint 1:`

> Louise Clark, the person who founded Pan's People, [died at 63](https://www.bbc.com/news/uk-england-19383596) of heart failure (coronary artery **disease**). And don't worry, the link will not contain a dead body.

`Hint 2:`

> Pan the demon and God were mainly apart of **Roman** and/or **Greek** mythology, which are languages. Pan's People was also a British dance troupe, so that language was **English**. But I can't fit the other clues.

`Hint 3:`

> **PAN** is $3$ letters long.

`Hint 4:`

> You can "**pan** out" with the $3$ words?

Comment: I think as part of the language hint, pan is also the French pronunciation of "pain" meaning bread. Bread can satiate or be half your needs, i.e. "man can not live on bread alone". And if you burn bread (shriek) then the smoke alarm may sound.

Comment: cna cna vf na nynez pnyy n fgrc qbja sebz znlqnl

Comment: @stuartstevenson Ah, that is well thought. Also, regarding how "man cannot live on bread alone", I was just studying that passage for the Philosophy Stack Exchange, incidentally! **Great minds think alike** ;)

Comment: @KateGregory Fb, jbhyq guvf or eryrinag sbe gur "fuevrx" cneg gura? ;)

Comment: @user477343 precisely

Comment: Pandemic for diseases/people. "these three love to follow me" being related to the language tag _might_ mean all three have "pan" as prefix. Although I have to say given that Pan _is_ already a demon _and_ a deity it's a little hard to find which _other_ figures starting with pan are a demon and deity respectively

Comment: Also, I'm surprised pantry isn't correct. hmmmm. Oh, and just realized "If you put these 3 behind me, you get 3 words.". So the clued words form _more_ words when appended to "PAN". And ignoring that fourth hint, "pantheon" might work for gods

Comment: Pandemonium is where the demons live (note that pandemonium also contains "demon") and the deity can be considered "Always carousing, happy and merry", at least according to more modern interpretations. Possibly. Also, note that the last three lines clue for a single word. weird.

Comment: @somebody You should try putting the stuff you wrote into a partial answer; there's a clue that no one else solved yet I think.

Comment: Specifically I'm talking about the people/diseases clue.

Answer (score 3):

People, demons, deities -

> Don't know for people, but for demons it could be pandemonium and for deities it could be pantheon.

Cupboards, crumbs, committees - it could be:

> Pantry, panko (as in panko breadcrumbs), panel

Comment: could you please explain your answer? Thanks!

Comment: Just trying to find words that match to the clues.

Comment: All correct! It would be great if you could explain the roots to the first set of words you wrote. Bonus if you explain how the words in the second set are different from the words in the first set.

Answer (score 2):

Is 7:

> [Pan](https://www.greekmythology.com/Other_Gods/Pan/pan.html)? Always cavorting with nymphs, drunk, happy, scary, etc...?

Comment: That's what I thought! I won't put the idea in my answer though because you brought it up first :P $(+1)$

Comment: Correct; that's what I had in mind.